# Xpath or CSS selector get specific node

Tags: xpath, selenium, css-selectors

I need to know if 1324 was Win or Loss in a table. How do I select the single `<td>` Element to know if it was a loss or a win.

```
<tr>
    <td> 1323 </td>
    <td> Won </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> 1324 </td>
    <td> Loss </td>
</tr>
[...]
<tr>
    <td> 1328 </td>
    <td> Won </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "select the single <td> Element to know if it was a loss or a win"?

Answer (score 1):

Whilst the answers are correct in this question, people are forgetting the context: **Selenium**. You give those XPath's to it, and it'll blow up in your face.

Selenium expects XPath queries to return physical DOM elements, and not attributes from those elements.

You should find the element, and use Selenium to get it's text. This could be `.getText()`, or `.Text` or something similar in whatever language you are using (C# and Java examples below - assuming `driver` is a valid `Driver` instance):

**C#**:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[text()="1324"]/following-sibling::td")).Text;
```

**Java**:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[text()="1324"]/following-sibling::td")).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//td[text()='1324']/../td[2]/text()
```